# google ima script not loading in Cordova application

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-ima

I am working on android application wrapped w/ Cordova.  The application uses google ima to display ads : [Google IMA](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/)

When I try to reference any functions e.g :

```
adDisplayContainer =  new google.ima.AdDisplayContainer(document.getElementById('adContainer'));
```

I get the following error:  "ReferenceError: google is not defined".

I have a script tag with src="http://imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js" in the body of index.html. I have tried it in the head as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified a protocol and ran "cordova build android" and that seem to have done the trick.

I have tried using a src with no protocol as well `src="http://imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"`